# how to fix: list indices must be integers, not str - while querying json data

Tags: python

I'm doing a get request (json output) with:

```
url = "https://"+user+":"+api+"@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/"+id+"/getSoftwareComponents"

querystring = {"objectMask":"mask[passwords]"}

headers = {
   'cache-control': "no-cache"
    }
response = requests.get( url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
pwdata = response.json()
print (json.dumps(pwdata, indent=2))
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "manufacturerLicenseInstance": "", 
    "passwords": [
      {
        "username": "test", 
        "modifyDate": "2018-05-11T21:52:54+09:00", 
        "softwareId": 36440389, 
        "id": 38400901, 
        "port": null, 
        "password": "xxxxxxxx", 
        "createDate": "2018-05-11T21:52:54+09:00", 
        "software": null
      }
    ], 
    "hardwareId": null, 
    "id": 36440389
  }, 
  {
    "manufacturerLicenseInstance": "", 
    "passwords": [
      {
        "username": "nabe", 
        "modifyDate": "2018-05-11T21:52:54+09:00", 
        "softwareId": 36440391, 
        "id": 38402045, 
        "port": null, 
        "password": "xxxxxxx", 
        "createDate": "2018-05-11T21:52:54+09:00", 
        "software": null
      }
    ], 
    "hardwareId": null, 
    "id": 36440391
  }
]
```

From the above output, I'm trying to filter `id` values in `passwords[]` with:

`pwdid = [pwd['id'] for pwd in pwdata['passwords']]`

or

`pwdid = pwdata['passwords'][4]['id']`

Both of them gives `list indices must be integers, not str` error

Apparently, something is not correct with the way I'm using list `pwd['id']`.

Comment: You're _literally_ giving the indices as strings

Comment: `"passwords": [{}]` itself is a list of dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cricket is right, you have an error because you subset a list with a string. Try this:

```
[ [ pwd["id"] for pwd in instance["passwords"]] for instance in pwdata]
```

Answer (score 0):

Extracting password ids from 'data'

```
data = [
    {
        "manufacturerLicenseInstance": "",
        "passwords": [
            {
                "username": "test",
                "modifyDate": "2018-05-11T21:52:54+09:00",
                "softwareId": 36440389,
                "id": 38400901,
                "port": None,
                "password": "xxxxxxxx",
                "createDate": "2018-05-11T21:52:54+09:00",
                "software": None
            }
        ],
        "hardwareId": None,
        "id": 36440389
    },
    {
        "manufacturerLicenseInstance": "",
        "passwords": [
            {
                "username": "nabe",
                "modifyDate": "2018-05-11T21:52:54+09:00",
                "softwareId": 36440391,
                "id": 38402045,
                "port": None,
                "password": "xxxxxxx",
                "createDate": "2018-05-11T21:52:54+09:00",
                "software": None
            }
        ],
        "hardwareId": None,
        "id": 36440391
    }
]
ids = [pwd['id'] for sublist in [entry['passwords'] for entry in data] for pwd in sublist]
print(ids)
```

output

```
[38400901, 38402045]
```

Easier to read version

```
ids = []
password_dict_list = [entry['passwords'] for entry in data]
for entry in password_dict_list:
    for sub_entry in entry:
        ids.append(sub_entry['id'])
print(ids)
```

output

```
[38400901, 38402045]
```